# regular expression for "11th to 16th letter"

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am new to regular expression. Need help for reading files in `unix` system. I want to apply regular expression on `ls` command.

I have below files :

> DLERMS0800**170816**1708209683.csv.gz
>
> DLERMS1300**170816**1330170816.csv.gz
>
> DLERMS13001708171330170816.csv.gz

and would like to extract files which have 170816 between 11th record to 16th digit.

I tried with below command `ls *170816*.gz`. However I am getting 3 filenames instead of two. I want only first two filenames instead of all 3. Could you please help.

Also want to add here that my third filename already contains 170816 at the end DLERMS13001708171330`170816`.csv.gz. I want to avoid this in my `ls` command output.

Comment: This is not regex, this is wildcard. You want to use the wildcard for "any single letter" appropriatly often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash` parameter-expansion alone,

```
for file in *.csv.gz; do  
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    [ "${file:10:6}" == "170816" ] && printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

> `${PARAMETER:OFFSET:LENGTH}`
>
> This one can expand only a part of a parameter's value, given a position to start and maybe a length. If `LENGTH` is omitted, the parameter will be expanded up to the end of the string. If `LENGTH` is negative, it's taken as a second offset into the string, counting from the end of the string

---

Based on comments from below, apparently OP wants to copy the files intended to an alternate path, in which case the `printf()` should be replaced with `cp` with necessary arguments

```
[ "${file:10:6}" == "170816" ] && cp -- "$file" path/to/destination
```

Comment: Why would you want to do all that when you could just use `printf '%s\n' ??????????170816*.gz`, possibly with `nullglob`?

Comment: @TomFenech: Fair point, wanted to suggest use of a proper loop also and to probably code golfing by reducing number of `?` characters. Nothing more.

Comment: Code golfing against the single line answers below?

Comment: @Yunnosch: I usually care about how effective the code is (without bad practices) and not worrying about how many line it takes.

Comment: All three filenames contain 170816. However I would like to extract first two filenames in which 11-16 characters are 170816 and want to ignore same string in rest filenames. I could not achieve this from above code. Could you please suggest new code.

Comment: @Cast_A_Way: Not sure why  you claim you cannot achieve this. This code does exactly that. It is looking at characters from 11 to 16 to check if it has `170816`. I tested the code before posting it and it returned the two files and dropped the third file from your example

Comment: Thanks Inian. I tested your code and it worked for me.
Actually I want above logic for copying files from one location to other.

Comment: @Cast_A_Way if you just want to copy a list of files one one place to another, you don't need a loop. A simple `cp ??????????170816*.gz path/to/destination` is probably fine. But you should really edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to do, so we can give you better advice.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, be careful not to confuse regular expressions with shell glob patterns (which is what you want here).

Your glob could be:

```
??????????170816*.gz
```

Which matches 10 unknown characters followed by the sequence you specified.

Depending on your next step, you might not need to use `ls` at all, for example you can loop over these files like this:

```
for file in ??????????170816*.gz; do 
    something_with "$file"
done
```

Or output the files that match using one of the following:

```
echo ??????????170816*.gz
printf '%s\n' ??????????170816*.gz
```

If there is a possibility that no files match, then you may wish to consider enabling `nullglob` (using `shopt -s nullglob`), which would expand to nothing in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), it's not the same as using regular expression.

In your example you can use "?" as a placeholder for matching a single character:

Hence to achieve what you want as output, use ls with pattern below -

```
 ls ??????????170816*
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the wildcard (not regex) "any single letter" `?` appropriatly often.

```
ls DLERMS????170816*.csv.gz
```

Regexes are much more flexible/powerful and overkill for this simple use case.
But as far as I know, ls does not support them, so you would have to go via other bash tools to identify the files in case you ever need to actually use regexes for anything.

I also reflected what I perceive to be another common of your filenames, the DLERMS at the beginning, if that is NOT common, replace those letter by `?`, too.

Comment: The pattern is expanded by the shell and passed to `ls`, so this isn't really a question of whether `ls` supports anything.

Comment: @TomFenech Regex would NOT be expanded by the shell, be passed to ls, be not understood. In the end it would fail because ls does not support regexes. What is your point? I did not say that globbing/wildcards work because they are understood by ls.

Comment: No, the shell would expand the pattern as if it were a glob (possibly evaluating to itself in the case that nothing matched), and the result would be passed as a list of arguments to `ls`. To pass something literally to `ls` you would need to use single quotes. But the point is that `ls` isn't doing anything other than printing the arguments that are passed to it, so talking about whether it supports regular expressions or not is irrelevant. The important thing is that the shell doesn't support them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`ls ??????????170816*`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use regular expressions with `ls` directly, but with `egrep`, it works fine.

```
ls * | egrep "DLERMS[0-9]{4}170816[0-9]{10}.csv.gz"
```

[0-9]{4} - any number, four times.
[0-9]{10} - any number, ten times.

Also could be used instead "egrep" the command "grep -E", the -E option allows especial regular expressions like "[{|" without need to escape them "\".

Answer (score 0):

A solution with find and regex

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex "^.{12}170816.*\.gz"
```

find read: ./xxxxxxxxxxxxx and .{12} means the first twelve, so 170816 is the expression between 13th record to 18th